# AWS EC2 getting a new dynamic IP without shutting down and start back up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am testing a component that required **changing the IP address** for every test.

Using EC2, I can perform the following actions to change my IP:

1. Shutdown the VM
2. Start up the VM
3. New IP obtained

While that work wonderfully, I need to wait 3 mins for it so shutdown and start back up for each test, which become quite troublesome overtime.

Would like to ask if there is anyway to, click a button / execute a script and obtain a new IP instantly? Thanks.

Comment: How about using Elastic IP address? Allocate (new EIP), Associate, Test, Disassociate, Release will be one sequence. It's faster than shutting down and restart. You can write a script to do this.

Comment: Do you need a different Public IP address, or a Private IP address?

Comment: *Do you need a different Public IP address, or a Private IP address?* A different Public IP

Comment: @shimo Your solution seems promising! Let me take a look, many thanks!

Comment: @shimo I tried your solution and it works wonderfully! One modification I made is instead of releasing it and creating a new Elastic IP, I just *associate > disassociate > test > assocaite > disassociate > test > ...* and repeat, because every time I disassociate it will create a new IP for me which is what I am looking for already. Can you mark that as an answer so I can accept it? Many thanks!

Comment: @Ng Sek Long Good to hear you've done! I have post an answer and shared the code I tried myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Elastic IP address (EIP), you can allocate new IP addresses faster than stopping and starting the EC2 inctance.

Here is a snippet with Python boto3 for checking IP addresses are changed.

**Prerequisite**

- boto3
- EC2 instance (InstanceID)
- No EIP in the region

**Code**

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def check_eip():
    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
    res_describe = ec2.describe_addresses()

    if res_describe["Addresses"]:
        return res_describe["Addresses"][0]["PublicIp"]
    else:
        return "NO EIP"

InstanceID = "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")

try:
    print("Step0: ", check_eip())

    allocation = ec2.allocate_address(Domain="vpc")
    print("Step1: ", check_eip())

    response = ec2.associate_address(
        AllocationId=allocation["AllocationId"], InstanceId=InstanceID
    )
    print("Step2: ", check_eip())

    # Do something here with the new EIP

    response2 = ec2.disassociate_address(
        AssociationId=response["AssociationId"])
    print("Step3: ", check_eip())

    response3 = ec2.release_address(AllocationId=allocation["AllocationId"])
    print("Step4: ", check_eip())

except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

The output will be like this:

```
Step0:  NO EIP
Step1:  aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Step2:  aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Step3:  aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Step4:  NO EIP
```

- It takes several seconds to run one sequence.
- Whey you run the code again, EIP will be changed.

**Note**

Please make sure to release unused EIP.

> $0.005 per Elastic IP address not associated with a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis

Comment: Does aws charge anything if I do lots of these re-maps of ip?